# c# printing template word file

Tags: c#, windows, printing, ms-word

I want to print certificates from the list and I have a template word file. All the time I copy only one name from the list and paste to that draft word file and print. So if you think there are more than 500 names at the same time, it is starting to being trouble for me :) So;
I want to ask,
Is it possible to put the names on one list and print all names with only one button using the template word file? 
the template has only the measurements actually for bring the name to the center. I hope you guys can save me from this trouble :)
Have a nice day!

Comment: You mean like "Mail-merge"?

Comment: [How do you mail merge a word document in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874300/how-do-you-mail-merge-a-word-document-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No. As you know in the certificates there is a center line for the name. I want to paste the name there and print.

Comment: but it needs to be continuously. Program will take the name from the list then put the name to the center of the page then print. I hope I could explain :)

Comment: This is what mail merge does. You place a field on the page, and this page is printed repeatedly for reach record in your data source, filling the field with different values.

Comment: Exactly. So do you have any suggestions about how to write this? I am really new on these things and if you send me a youtube video source or something like that, I will be appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can acomplish this by using MS Word templates with one of the libraries which are capable of manipulating OpenXML (native docx format). See [this example](http://www.docentric.com/product/how-to-use) to find out more.